# Gitlab SSH not working after changing Gitlab profile name

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

Everything was working until I updated my Gitlab account name. I tried to push a repo I was working on to the remote but the command would just hang up until I ctl+c. I already had SSH set up so this shouldn't happen.

To troubleshoot, I created a repo on the website and cloned it via HTTPS and everything worked. If I tried to clone it via SSH it would also hang up.

I followed [GitLabs official docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/) to create a new ssh key. Verifying the key with gitlab fails. This doc is what I used to create my key the first time and was working for months.

```
stephen@stephen:~/Projects$ git clone https://gitlab.com/sat1017/cs61b.git
Cloning into 'cs61b'...
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
stephen@stephen:~/Projects$ cd cs61b/
stephen@stephen:~/Projects/cs61b$ touch READ.md
stephen@stephen:~/Projects/cs61b$ git add READ.md 
stephen@stephen:~/Projects/cs61b$ git commit -m 'init'
[master (root-commit) 5ff8c04] init
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 READ.md
stephen@stephen:~/Projects/cs61b$ git push -u origin master
Username for 'https://gitlab.com': sat1017
Password for 'https://sat1017@gitlab.com': 
Enumerating objects: 3, done.
Counting objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 215 bytes | 215.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To https://gitlab.com/sat1017/cs61b.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
Branch 'master' set up to track remote branch 'master' from 'origin'.
stephen@stephen:~/Projects/cs61b$ git remote -v
origin  https://gitlab.com/sat1017/cs61b.git (fetch)
origin  https://gitlab.com/sat1017/cs61b.git (push)
stephen@stephen:~/Projects$ rm -rf cs61b/
stephen@stephen:~/Projects$ git clone git@gitlab.com:sat1017/cs61b.git
Cloning into 'cs61b'...
^C
```

So I thought maybe the SSH key somehow got deleted.

```
stephen@stephen:~/Projects/cs61b$ ls -al ~/.ssh/
total 20
drwx------  2 stephen stephen 4096 May 27 22:09 .
drwxr-xr-x 32 stephen stephen 4096 Nov 13 12:20 ..
-rw-------  1 stephen stephen  484 Nov 13 12:57 id_ed25519
-rw-r--r--  1 stephen stephen  113 Nov 13 12:57 id_ed25519.pub
-rw-r--r--  1 stephen stephen 1992 Jun 15 21:47 known_hosts
```

But verifying it worked via the gitlab docs also showed that somewhere the SSH connection was failing. The pub key is already added to my profile.

```
stephen@stephen:~/Projects/cs61b$ ssh -Tvvv git@gitlab.com
OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "gitlab.com" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to gitlab.com [2606:4700:90:0:f22e:fbec:5bed:a9b9] port 22.
^C
```

So my only idea of what is wrong is somewhere, whether my local machine or the gitlab server, my SSH credentials are cached and are pointing to the wrong gitlab namespace.

Comment: You should always generate your ssh key using your **mail id**. For gitlab, we also used to face the similar issue like yours. But, after we adopt the practice of generating ssh keys using mail id, there are no such problem. So, I guess you have created ssh keys for your username and when you changed, this caused the issue with ssh. It's worth checking, could you check once.

Comment: @SouravAtta could you explain further “created ssh keys for your username”. I created ssh keys and xclipped it into my profiles ssh key tab. Shouldn’t that be linked to my mail? The mail of my profile never changed.

Comment: No, putting the ssh keys into in your gitlab profile will not attach it with email. Here is the command to do generate ssh-key using your mail id, so that you will never face issue with the change of username ssh-key changed  `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C your-email-address`

Comment: When you have created ssh key in your server, it was created for that specific user in server. But say me this, do you have the same username in your gitlab ?? I guess NO. Hope this will help https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/

Comment: @SouravAtta those were the docs I was following. I used that exact command with my email. Still doesn't work. -C is only a comment so I don't think it would have anything to do with the verification process of SSH.